# Why is my while loop to test if year of birth has 4 chars and starts with 1 or 2 infinite?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I am still a beginner and I've been trying to fix this for half an hour to no avail. It's probably an easy fix but I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If you answer my question, please explain the reasoning very clearly because I usually understand assignment operators but clearly this one is over my head.
Thank you!

```
// Calculating your age with your date of birth
// yob is the year of birth
var yob = parseInt(prompt('What ur date of birth', 1995));

function calcage (yob){
    while ((yob[0] != 1 && yob[0] !=2) || (yob.length != 4)) {
        // I don't understand why this is an infinite loop.
        // while yob doesn't start with one 
//or doesn't start with two or     yob length is smaller than 4. 
    // Then ask the question again.
    var yob = parseInt(prompt(' Please enter a valid date of birth. What     your date of birth ', 1995));
}
    var age = 2017 - yob;
return age;
}

var yourage = calcage(yob);
document.write("You are "+yourage+" years old");
```

Comment: `yob` is an integer, not an array, nor a string. Also consider using the second radix parameter on `parseInt()` to specify the base in order to avoid weird bugs.

Comment: .... which means `yob[0]` is `undefined`. You cannot access the digits of a number with the `[]` operator unless you convert the number to a string first.

Comment: function calcage (yob){
    var yob = yob.toString(); I used this and it worked. Thank you both!

Comment: Instead of messy string comparison, why not compare it as an integer in your while condition? `while (yob < 1000 || yob >= 3000)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, not sure why I hadn't thought of this! If you post it as an answer I'll pick you for best answer

Answer (score 0):

When you use `yob[0]` like this I am assuming that you are trying to find the first digit of yob.

This is not really gonna work that way ***unless*** you convert the value of yob to a string. If you do that you can find the first digit of yob or technically since you converted it to a string it would be the first character